# Match end of a string using a Regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash, devops, grafana

I am using Grafana Dashboard. I have the following servers:

```
ip-10-2-32-214.ec2.internal
ip-10-2-33-184.ec2.internal
ip-10-2-34-13.ec2.internal
ip-10-2-34-213.ec2.internal
ip-10-2-36-165.ec2.internal
ip-10-2-36-219.ec2.internal
ip-10-2-36-77.ec2.internal
ip-10-2-37-79.ec2.internal
ip-10-2-38-252.ec2.internal
ip-10-2-39-216.ec2.internal
ip-10-2-40-242.ec2.internal
ip-10-2-40-52.ec2.internal
ip-10-2-43-220.ec2.internal
ip-10-2-44-192.ec2.internal
ip-10-2-45-148.ec2.internal
ip-10-2-46-215.ec2.internal
ip-10-2-47-152.ec2.internal
ip-10-2-48-91.ec2.internal
ip-10-2-49-237.ec2.internal
ip-10-2-50-200.ec2.internal
ip-10-2-52-49.ec2.internal
ip-10-2-53-14.ec2.internal
ip-10-2-56-137.ec2.internal
ip-10-2-57-108.ec2.internal
ip-10-2-60-105.ec2.internal
ip-10-2-61-250.ec2.internal
ip-10-2-63-177.ec2.internal
```

But I want to match only server that end with those numbers:

```
184|200|165|220|237|137|242|(.ec2.internal)
```

As u see I tried this regex but it not working.

Comment: You can use `(184|200|165|220|237|137|242)\.ec2\.internal$` Your mistake was the last `|` before `(.ec2.internal)`which made it match either one of the number OR the `.ec2.internal`, which I guess made it match line

Comment: What is your code? How are you trying your current pattern? What does not work?

Comment: "You tried this regex", but how, and with which tool, and what was the exact result? Tools use different regex flavours.

Comment: Issue is that I get only this value in grafana: https://i.imgur.com/p2zqTwz.png and without regex I get https://i.imgur.com/9Dnlv0c.png

Comment: Why ti doesn't get filtered

Comment: Why not just `184|200|165|220|237|137|242`?

Comment: I don't know why but first example, didn't work, but 184|200|165|220|237|137|242 , worked :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked for me 184|200|165|220|237|137|242